# WPF usercontrol out of bounds of the Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid

I have a WPF app that I'm testing which loads a XML and visualizes it in a usercontrol. Now the issue I'm having is that every time I load my user control the `HorizontalAlignment` is okay, but the `VerticalAlignment` doesn't adept to the height size of the usercontrol.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

MainWindow.xaml

```
        <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UserControls="clr-namespace:RackBuildingTesT.UserControls" x:Class="RackBuildingTesT.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="578" Width="758" SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged_1">
<Grid>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="Welke rack laden" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="RackChooser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="RackChooser_SelectionChanged"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <Grid x:Name="RackGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadRackCombo();
    }
    private void LoadRackCombo()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Properties.Settings.Default.FilePathXMLRack);
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            RackChooser.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void RackChooser_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RackGrid.Children.Clear();
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        if (RackChooser.SelectedIndex == -1)
            MessageBox.Show("Select a rack");
        else
        {
            string rackFile = Convert.ToString(RackChooser.Items[RackChooser.SelectedIndex]);
            UserControls.RackBuilder r = new UserControls.RackBuilder();
            RackGrid.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            RackGrid.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
            r.Width = RackGrid.Width;
            r.Height = RackGrid.Height;
            var _r = TRack.CreateFromXMLFile(rackFile, null);
            r.set_Rack(_r);
            RackGrid.Children.Add(r);
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void Window_SizeChanged_1(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RackGrid.Width = this.Width;
        RackGrid.Height = this.Height;
    }
```

RackBuilder.xaml.cs (xaml page is standard WPF usercontrol)

```
        public RackBuilder()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TRack fRack { get; set; }

    public void set_Rack(TRack value)
    {
        this.fRack = value;
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (this.fRack != null)
        {
            var xScale = this.Width / this.fRack.Size.Width;
            var yScale = this.Height / this.fRack.Size.Height;
            var smallest = 0.0;

            if (xScale < yScale)
                smallest = xScale;
            else
                smallest = yScale;

            foreach (var hole in this.fRack.HolePositions)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Aquamarine, null, new Point(hole.Position.X * xScale, hole.Position.Y * yScale),
                                           hole.Diameter * smallest * 0.5, hole.Diameter * smallest * 0.5);
            }
        }
    }
```

Result

[image: Result of App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with putting the MainWindow `SizeToContent` to `WidthAndHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding your Control to a `Grid`, use the [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) and add it to its Content-Property.
It also stretches its child automatically.

Comment: I copied your xaml code and it behaved like expected. Make sure youre not manipulating the RackBuilders Height and Width, neither in code-behind nor in the UserControls xaml-code.